# Limit with column value

Tags: mysql

I have three tables: `questions`, `tests` and `relation` (test_dynamic_questions)

```
CREATE TABLE `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  `instructorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `question` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `question` varchar(1000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `image` longblob,
  `type` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT '0 - MCQ / 1 - T/F /2- COMPLETE/',
  `isTrue` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `instructorID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `deleted` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


CREATE TABLE `test_dynamic_questions` (
  `testID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `courseID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `questionsCount` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `randomOrder` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I want to do the following query:

```
 SELECT id 
   FROM question q
  WHERE deleted = 0 
    AND courseID IN (SELECT tdq.courseID 
                       FROM test_dynamic_questions tdq 
                      WHERE testID = 8)
  ORDER 
     BY RAND() LIMIT (SELECT questionsCount FROM test_dynamic_questions tq WHERE tq.courseID = q.courseID)
```

but select is not allowed in limit clause so is there anyway I can make this work?

Comment: Specify MySQL version. In general - enumerate and select only records with proper numbers.

Comment: @Akina MySQL 8.0

Comment: Look the solution in [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cedb48b627943ca1d84031759c6b7c23). You may test. If some problems occures, then create new question with the code (including my query), sample data (link to a fiddle with added INSERT INTO to it), and problem description.

Comment: @Strawberry The theme by the link provided do NOT solve the problem. It only tells "No solution". Look at my fiddle - my code really solves the problem using features added in 8.0 version (OP tells his server version is 8). So closing this question is error at least. And if OP will not create another question where my code will be posted, then this solution will be unsearcheable (read - will be lost).

Comment: @akina You can always ask and answer your own question.